# ASP.NET Core MVC : when partial view script

Tags: scripting, asp.net-core-mvc, partial

In ASP.NET Core MVC, when I used a partial view and add dynamic Javascript event to it using the `document.addEvenetListner`, the event is not working.

1. Parent View -vWHosiptalGeneralScrning.cshtml
2. Child View  -LabInves.cshtml

   I have 2 view 1 is parent view which name is vWHosiptalGeneralScrning and other is child view which code is in below, When i render child view directly the function fn_LabCatChange call properly,
   When i render through parent view and render child view using ajax call the function fn_LabCatChange not working.

[image: Child View]

[image: Parent View Render child view in highlited line]

Comment: could you provide related code for us to reproduce your issue?